# Run Python script in Windows with ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I could run my Python3.7 script in MacOS10 successfully, but when running in latest Windows10 Enterprise, the errors shows as below in my Python code, not sure if there is any solution to fix?

The sample data of my code is as below:

```
      A     B      C     D  Month
0     11    23     23   25    1
1     11    24     NA   26    2
2     12    20     18   18    1
3     12    NA     20   10    2

col=['Month','A','B','C']
df[col] = df[col].groupby(['A'], sort=False, as_index=False).ffill()
```

Error Message in Windows environment is as below:

```
 df[col] = df[col].groupby(['A'], sort=False, as_index=False).ffill()
 File "C:\Users\....\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3469, in __setitem__
 self._sentitem_array(key, value)

File "C:\Users\....\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3492, in _setitem_array
    raise ValueError('Columns must be same length as key')

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Comment: Paste your code, not an image!

Comment: Code is follow the image. Image is just the error message.

Comment: Please copy and paste the stacktrace though, that image is very low quality and the message is barely legible.